# How to restore an oracle database from a manual cold backup on different server?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have all the contents of the oradata folder and my intuition tells me that on the new server I just need to install [image]oracle binaries of the same version, recreate the directory structure, create a new database with the same name, and then replace the database files with the ones I want restore.

Something else?

Comment: Yes, quite a few other things, potentially. At the very least, an initialization file (usually located in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs. To be safe, you should use the RMAN utility to backup your source database and then restore that to the target server.

Comment: I don't have access to source database. Only to those database files.

Comment: At the very least you would also need the init parameter file (pfile and/or spfile). If the server used any kind of encryption you would also need the encryption keys; then there's sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora content, oratab, and possibly others. Oracle keeps a variety of config files and settings scattered around in several directories (or in the Windows Registry), not just the data files; this is one reason why it is important to use the actual RMAN utility when copying a DB to a new server. You can't just take a copy of the data files and expect everything to work correctly.

Comment: Ideally, you'd also need to confirm that the binary files contained the exact same patches as the source server, too: especially for quarterly critical patch updates or any one-off bug fixes. Do you have that information? If so, you might be able to "fake" your way through creating a pfile by creating a temporary database and adapting its pfile and spfile to your data files.